# Estimate the integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

$(x_0,x_1,...,x_n)$ is a point from $[0,1]^{n+1}$ and $\sum_{i=0}^{n} x_i=1$.

Consider $I=\int \int \cdots \int \sqrt{\sum_{i=0}^{n} (x_i-\frac{1}{n+1})^2}dx_0\cdots dx_n=\int_{[0,1]^{n+1} }\sqrt{\sum_{i=0}^{n} (x_i-\frac{1}{n+1})^2} dV_{n+1}$.

I am hoping to find some constants $c$ and $C$ such that $\frac{c}{\sqrt{n}}\leq I\leq \frac{C}{\sqrt{n}}$

It doesn't seem possible to calculate with spherical parametrization. Is there any other way to estimate without involving polar coordination parametrization?

Comment: According to the constraint that $\sum\limits_{i=0}^nx_i=1$, $x$ lives in an $n$-dimensional submanifold of $[0,1]^{n+1}$. An $n+1$ dimensional integral over an $n$-dimensional manifold vanishes.